# Access: Disable 'clear all filters' on Toolbar (vba)

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to disable the Toolbar option to 'clear all filters' in Access 2013.

I found the following VBA codes that did all not work for me:

```
Application.CommandBars("Records").Controls(4).Enabled = False
Application.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls("Data").Enabled = False
Application.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls("Filter").Enabled = False
```

One solution I found is to disable the whole toolbar like this:

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
```

I don't want to use this option because everything (including search toolbar) is disabled.

Can I achieve this with the 'CommandBars' code somehow?

Comment: The old `Application.CommandBars` code won't work, it is for the toolbars in Office <= 2003. With the ribbon, things seem to be a little more complicated. This may be a start:  http://www.verboon.info/2011/08/how-to-disable-office-ribbon-items-using-group-policy/

Comment: Please add the tag for the Access version you are using.

Comment: @Andre This would apply to all Files and not just one specific file. Thanks anyway I'll keep this option in mind.

Comment: Oh. I'm afraid you will be out of luck. Custom ribbon XML in a specific file can never modify the in-built ribbon elements, only custom groups/elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the record selection bar when looking at a Form, you could turn off the Form's "Allow Filters" Property.

That seemed to do it for me... And then it didn't on other Forms, but it's a thing to try...